# Can we replace Pusher with Google cloud messaging for push notification in laravel?

Tags: laravel, firebase-cloud-messaging, pusher

We are developing an app using Laravel 8.3 for back-end, our boss is forcing as to keep all of our (3dr pray services) as less as possible, so most of the services that we need can be provided by Google & firebase.

we have a real-time chat inside the app.

Now the question:

- Can we replace Pusher with Google cloud messaging for push notification?
- will the (online/offline) and (seen/read) be as good as pusher?
- 

if yes, what driver to use inside the .env file?

Thank you

Comment: yes, and, yes. pls. do a little research, I do not think SO is the place to ask this type of questions.

Comment: I really did, once I couldn't find the answer in google either here, I post my question here :)